# FirebaseUI `signInSuccessWithAuthResult` does not execute callback containing API call

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, axios

I am using FirebaseUI to handle authentication in a React, Express, Typescript application.

Right now I am trying to execute an API call within the callback function using axios, however, the callback function does not get called at all and I cannot figure out why.

Here is my code for the `uiConfig`

```js
var uiConfig = {
    signInFlow: "popup",
    signInSuccessUrl: "/profile",
    signInOptions: [firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID, firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID],

    callbacks: {
        // Create user entity upon new sign up 
        signInSuccessWithAuthResult: async (authResult: any) => {
            const userInfo = authResult.additionalUserInfo;
            if (userInfo.isNewUser) {
                const data = {
                    uid: userInfo.uid,
                    username: userInfo.uid
                }
                try {
                    const res = await Axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/user/', data)
                    console.log(res.data);
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    },
};
```

What I am trying to do is: Upon sign in of a new user, I create a user entity in a database using an express back end API. However whenever a new sign in is made, nothing happens, and nothing comes out in the console, as if the callback is never executed.

CORS is enabled on the backend and all API calls work via postman.

Comment: Hello Meowmi, I have the same issue, signInSuccessWithAuthResult never fires after login. Did you find the solution? Thanks!

Comment: @RaphaëlRoux I sadly did not find the solution, and just gave up on it :( I believe there is some way you can implement this using React context, but I am not too sure about it. All the best!